# Javascript get values inside an object and add them together?

Tags: javascript

I'm wondering if it's possible to loop through a set objects in Angular and then perform maths on the retrieved values.

I currently have an object (`$scope.basketItems`) and I'd like to know if it's possible (and if so how) to loop through each item inside `$scope.basketItems`, extract each `Price` and add together all  `Price`'s to create a total figure?

Comment: @PSL care to shed some light on the solution...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would most likely use lodash or underscore, something like this:

```
$scope.basketItems = [
    {name: 'bob', price: 50},
    {name: 'tim', price: 25},
    {name: 'sarah', price: 25}
];
$scope.sum = 0;

_.forEach( $scope.basketItems, function(item) {
    $scope.sum += item.price;
});
```

sum = 100;

Comment: I didn't use lodash/underscore but it was `+=` that's the key. Totally forgot about that because my brain has been fried...

Answer (score 1):

Use Javascript's [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) method, no need for any external libraries e.g:

```
$scope.basketItems = [{price: 123},{price: 456}];

$scope.total = $scope.basketItems.reduce(
    function(a,b) {
        return a.price + b.price;
    }
);
```